# Eventlog leakage issue(.net profiler shows undisposed)

Tags: c#, eventlog-source

I am writing error to event log but when i checked for leakage i got event log leakage in .net profiler, Do I need to dispose this object? Is it will create any issue in multi threading?

```
public override void ProcessWarning(string title, string message)
{
    if (title == null)
        eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
    else
        eventLog.WriteEntry(title + '\n' + message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the *relevant* code. Where do you define `eventLog`, where do you initialize it and why don't you dispose it in the parent class's Dispose method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [EventLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class extends [Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx), which shows that it implements `IDisposable`. So yes, you will need to (eventually) Dispose() of it.

Apparently your `eventLog` is a field in your class. This (an IDisposable field) means that your class needs to implement IDisposable itself. In your own Dispose method you will then need to dispose of that `eventLog`.

And of course this means that anything *using* this class must treat it as the IDisposable that it now is.